# c# (Azure Functions) - System.Private.CoreLib: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'stream')

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

I am completely new to C# and Visual Studio.

I am trying to develop Azure Functions where whenever I hit the endpoint I get the following error message:

```
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-12-06T09:16:43.271Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000004FD42D6E'.
[2023-12-06T09:16:49.705Z] Executed 'func-etis-orderdetails' (Failed, Id=1f0fb3e9-7d60-4de7-9adc-02f3d0dd6902, Duration=45ms)
[2023-12-06T09:16:49.708Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'stream').
[2023-12-06T09:16:49.715Z] An unhandled host error has occurred.
[2023-12-06T09:16:49.717Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'stream').
```

I am running it through the little green arrow button that present on top of Visual Studio:

[image]

How do I resolve this error ?

Core tools info:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554
```

Comment: > Do you have local.settings.json file created with the content here -{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I have deleted my `local.settings.json`. I have no local settings

Comment: Add the file and also Do you have azure functions core tools installed -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Cisolated-process%2Cnode-v4%2Cpython-v2%2Chttp-trigger%2Ccontainer-apps&pivots=programming-language-csharp#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai But before that I had everything same as mentioned except instead of "dotnet-isolated" it was "dotnet".

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I have added the core tools information in the question

Comment: It is working on my end -https://i.imgur.com/NfWnbeQ.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256177/discussion-between-siddheshdesai-and-ng-newbie).

Answer (score 0):

I tried tweaking your code and was able to run the Function with the below implementation:-

I am not using Startup.cs file as its not required for `.NET 6.0` `v4` **HttpTrigger Function**

**My Function1.cs:-**

```cs
using func_etis_orderdetails.Interface;
using Integration.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp84
{
    public class OrderDetailsFunction
    {
        private readonly IOrderDetails orderDetails;

        public OrderDetailsFunction(IOrderDetails orderDetails)
        {
            this.orderDetails = orderDetails;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                // Logging initialization
                Logger.Initialize("correlationId", "interfaceId", "componentName", "logSource");

                // Extract necessary information from the request
                string sortFields = req.Query["sortFields"];
                int offset = int.Parse(req.Query["offset"]);
                int limit = int.Parse(req.Query["limit"]);
                string query = req.Query["query"];
                var token = req.Headers["BYOMS_TOKEN_HEADER"].ToString(); // Replace with actual header key
                var businessKey = req.Headers["X_BUSINESS_KEY"].ToString(); // Replace with actual header key
                var correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // Replace with actual correlation ID logic
                var componentName = "YourComponentName"; // Replace with actual component name
                var startTime = DateTime.Now;

                // Fetch order details using IOrderDetails implementation
                var orderDetailsResponse = await orderDetails.GetOrderDetails(
                    sortFields,
                    offset,
                    limit,
                    query,
                    token,
                    businessKey,
                    correlationId,
                    startTime
                );

                return new OkObjectResult(orderDetailsResponse);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log and handle exceptions
                var logTemplate = new LogTemplate();
                ExceptionLogger.LogException("systemId", ex, logTemplate, DateTime.Now);

                var response = new ContentResult
                {
                    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                    Content = "Error occurred while processing the request"
                };

                return response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My local.settings.json:-**

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

***My other dependencies:-***

ExceptionLogger.cs:-

```cs
using System;

namespace Integration.Logging
{
    public static class ExceptionLogger
    {
        public static void LogException(string systemId, Exception ex, LogTemplate logTemplate, DateTime startTime)
        {
            // Your exception logging logic
        }
    }

    public class LogTemplate
    {
        // Define properties for logging template
    }
}
```

IOrderDetails.cs:-

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace func_etis_orderdetails.Interface
{
    public interface IOrderDetails
    {
        Task<OrderDetailsResponse> GetOrderDetails(string sortFields, int offset, int limit, string query, string token, string businessKey, string correlationId, DateTime startTime);
    }

    // You would define the OrderDetailsResponse class based on your actual response structure
    public class OrderDetailsResponse
    {
        // Define properties relevant to your response
    }
}
```

Logger.cs:-

```cs
using System;

namespace Integration.Logging
{
    public static class Logger
    {
        public static void Initialize(string correlationId, string interfaceId, string componentName, string logSource)
        {
            // Your initialization logic for logging
        }
    }
}
```

OrderDetails.cs:-

```cs
using func_etis_orderdetails.Interface;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace func_etis_orderdetails.Implementation
{
    public class OrderDetails : IOrderDetails
    {
        // Implement the interface method
        public async Task<OrderDetailsResponse> GetOrderDetails(string sortFields, int offset, int limit, string query, string token, string businessKey, string correlationId, DateTime startTime)
        {
            // Your implementation logic here to fetch order details
            // This method should return an instance of OrderDetailsResponse
            return new OrderDetailsResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

**host.json:-**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

[image]